# Fixing ELAN Trackpoint driver 31.21.7.1 touchpad downtime after click

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

On X1 Carbon G7 and X1 Yoga 4G, the ELAN Trackpoint driver (31.21.7.1) is causing downtime for the movement of the touchpad cursor. When the buttons above the touchpoint are clicked, the cursor does not move for around a second which is really bad for the user experience. It there a way to modify the driver so that this downtime does not occur anymore?

It happens under Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Is the source code available somewhere? Or are there alternative drivers that may work better?

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds540219

Answer (score 2):

So far, the best solution I have come up with (on ThinkPad P53 with Windows 10) is to simply disable the trackpoint. The latest Elan drivers on Windows 10 seems to have very few settings; it can be accessed from Settings > Mouse > TrackPoint settings. Then just click the slide to turn the trackpoint to Off.

This eliminated the problem with "trackpoint drift" causing my touchpad to freeze up for seconds a time. The only downside is: it also disables the physical mouse buttons located just above the touchpad, which I had been quite accustomed to using. I am currently training myself to use taps on the touchpad and/or the buttons below the touchpad :-)

---

You may also wish to check if your Lenovo models have an update available for "TrackPoint Firmware Update Utility for Windows 10". [Here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p53-type-20qn-20qq/20qn/downloads/DS505655) is the one for the Thinkpad P53, for reference. The ReadMe for that firmware update has this note in the Changes section:

> [Problem fixes]
>
> - Fixed long drift issue of ELAN TrackPoint.

Comment: I think in that case I would not be able to use the trackpoint buttons at all. I think you are mixing it up with a different issue.